# Two tab host in a single activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost

I am using Two tab host in my single activity. One for navigation drawer and other for my activity layout.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabHost
                android:id="@+id/customTabHost"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TabWidget
                        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                    </TabWidget>

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                        <ViewFlipper
                            android:id="@+id/view_flipper_one"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
                        </ViewFlipper>

                        <ViewFlipper
                            android:id="@+id/view_flipper_two"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
                        </ViewFlipper>

                        <ViewFlipper
                            android:id="@+id/view_flipper_three"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
                        </ViewFlipper>
                    </FrameLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </TabHost>
<TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_weight=".8"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                </ListView>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="This is another button" >
                </Button>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="This is a text" >
                </TextView>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
```

and in my activity -

```
    TabHost host = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec("tab1");
    spec.setContent(R.id.list);
    spec.setIndicator("Button1");

    host.addTab(spec);
    spec = host.newTabSpec("tab2");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec.setIndicator("Next Button");
    host.addTab(spec);
    spec = host.newTabSpec("tab3");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab3);
    spec.setIndicator("Just some text");
    host.addTab(spec);
    TabHost flipperHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.customTabHost);
    TabSpec flipperSpec = flipperHost.newTabSpec("tab4");
    flipperSpec.setContent(R.id.view_flipper_one);
    flipperSpec.setIndicator(getString(R.string.featured_reports));

    flipperHost.addTab(flipperSpec);
    flipperSpec = flipperHost.newTabSpec("tab5");
    flipperSpec.setContent(R.id.view_flipper_two);
    flipperSpec.setIndicator(getString(R.string.global_trends));
    flipperHost.addTab(flipperSpec);
    flipperSpec = flipperHost.newTabSpec("tab6");
    flipperSpec.setContent(R.id.view_flipper_three);
    flipperSpec.setIndicator(getString(R.string.tcs_perspectives));
    flipperHost.addTab(flipperSpec);
```

But it gives null pointer exception in second tab host spec line

```
  flipperSpec.setContent(R.id.view_flipper_one);
```

I have changed the ID of second tab host to R.id.customTabHost because I want to use both tab host on same activity. I don't know where the problem is?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post the stacktrace with the exception.

Comment: its not creating the tab spec object at tab4 - line TabSpec flipperSpec = flipperHost.newTabSpec("tab4"); So at next line - flipperSpec.setContent(R.id.view_flipper_one); its giving null pointer exception